undefined symbol : GetAsyncKeyState
I'm attempting to utilize the GetAsyncKeyState function in Assembly language to detect the state of a keyboard key. Specifically, I want to print a message when the user presses the "W" key. However, I encountered an "undefined symbol" error when attempting to use the GetAsyncKeyState function.
I've ensured that I've correctly included the user32.lib library file, and I'm using the correct function name in my code. I even tried manually adding extern GetAsyncKeyState: PROC to declare the GetAsyncKeyState function, but the issue persists.
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

.data
    message db "user32.lib is working!", 0
    msg db "You pressed 'W'", 0
.code
main proc
    invoke MessageBoxA, 0, ADDR message, ADDR caption, MB_OK
    call CheckForKey
main endp

CheckForKey PROC
    mov eax, 'W'
    call GetAsyncKeyState
    test eax, eax
    jz notPressed

    mov edx, OFFSET msg
    call WriteString
    jmp endCheck

notPressed:
    jmp endCheck

endCheck:
    ret
CheckForKey ENDP


end main

I want to test if I can print a string when I press 'W' using GetAsyncKeyState, but I encountered this error when using GetAsyncKeyState.I'm wondering what might be causing this error and how to resolve it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

You can add a prototype (after your includes) for it by adding the line GetAsyncKeyState PROTO STDCALL :DWORD . You can then use invoke GetAsyncKeyState, 'W' . Your main needs an invoke ExitProcess, 0 to terminate the program when finished.

Thank you for your help. The "undefined symbol" issue has been resolved now. However, when I press the W key on the keyboard, the program automatically terminates without displaying the message "You pressed 'W'".

You will need to put the AsyncGetKeyState in a loop. The function returns immediately. You probably didn't press W fast enough. If you end up in notPressed you shouldn't exit the function, you want to go back and call AsyncGetKeyStat, and keep looping until W is pressed. I assume you want this to basically wait until `'W`` is pressed and exit the program at that point.

Your process doesn't wait for your input and terminates. As @MichaelPetch said, you need a loop. Also see this GetAsyncKeyState example.

According to your and @MichaelPetch 's comment, adding the line GetAsyncKeyState PROTO STDCALL :DWORD solves the "undefined symbol" issue. You can also see How to call Windows API in x64 MASM program for extra information.
For the second issue,

However, when I press the W key on the keyboard, the program
automatically terminates without displaying the message "You pressed
'W'".

Also as @MichaelPetch said, you will need to put the AsyncGetKeyState in a loop. Your process doesn't wait for your input and terminates. See this GetAsyncKeyState example.
